# While using bitcoinjs-lib I am getting getAddress() is not fuction

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, bitcoin

Below are the code.

const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
    let testnet = bitcoin.networks.testnet;

```
let keypair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom({network: testnet});

let addr = keypair.getAddress();
let  pk = keypair.toWIF();
```

[image]

Comment: check the solution for this problem using the link below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63755772/8015494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
 const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey })
```

This seems to be what [the definitive example at github](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/addresses.js#L22) does.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass network parameter to ECPair.makeRandom directly without wrapper object and you will be there :)

```
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

let testnet = bitcoin.networks.testnet;
let keypair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom(testnet);

let addr = keypair.getAddress();
let pk = keypair.toWIF();
```